# How-to incorporate a UISegmentedControl inside a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I used the following tutorial [Red Artisan](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited) to create a UISegmentedControl which I use to switch between two views: a simple one and a table view.

Everything is fine when I create a new standalone project, but what I really want is to incorporate this functionality in another project with a UITabBarController as the rootController (the segmented control with two views will be inside the second tab).

In the above tutorial  the segmented control, navigation and segment controllers are  instantiated and configured from within the application delegate.

Any idea how this could be done from a lower level?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a `UITTabBarController` based application (There are LOTs of tutorials on how to do this), and then in the second `UIViewController` (or a custom subclass), you would create your `UISegmentedControl` to switch between two pages.

It sounds like you might also be using a `UINavigationController` as your base controller in the first application, if this is so..you could have a `UITabBarController` that has two Controllers in it (two tabs), and the second one will be a `UINavigationController` like how you had it setup in the app delegate.

Also, there are tutorials to do basically this exact thing all over the internet. Try searching for " `UINavigationController` inside `UITabBarController` " or similar. One other thing, there is an example of how the "layering" works in the Apple UI documentation for having a UINavigationController be one of the tabs of a UITabBarController (This is a quite common approach for iPhone apps)

Good luck!